# "R6025 - pure virtual call" in Display List, OpenGL, C++

Tags: c++, opengl, virtual

I'm creating a `Display list` for all GUI objects I have, like this:

```
glNewList(displayList, GL_COMPILE);
    obj->draw();
glEndList();
```

But when I try to compile it, I'm getting an error:

```
R6025 - pure virtual call
```

The `draw()` method is pure virtual. But I'd like to know, why can't I put virtual function inside `Display list`?

EDIT:

This is GUIObject class:

```
class GUIObject
{
protected:
    int m_id;
    int m_parentId;
    int m_width;
    int m_height;

    Point m_position;
    Point m_drawPosition;

    bool m_bEnabled;
    bool m_bVisible;

    GLuint m_displayListId;                     // Id in display lists array in TGUIManager

    virtual void onDrawStart() = 0;         
    virtual void onDrawFinish() = 0;        
public:
    virtual bool draw() = 0;

    void setDisplayListId(GLuint id);
    GLuint getDisplayListId();

    virtual int getWidth() const;
    virtual int getHeight() const;
    virtual bool pointInObject(const TPoint& point);

    GUIObject();

    virtual ~GUIObject();
};

GUIObject::GUIObject() : 
    m_position(Point(0,0)),
    m_width(0),
    m_height(0),
{
    m_drawPosition = m_position;
    GUIManager::Instance().addObject(this);
}

GUIObject::~GUIObject()
{
}
```

And here is `Button` class, which derives from `Component` which derives from `GUIObject`:

```
class Button : public Component, public Clickable
{
private:
    std::string m_text;
    TBackground* m_pBackground;
public:
    void setText(std::string text);
    void setBackground(Background* pBg);
    Background* getBackground() const;
    void setBackgroundOnClick(Background* pBg);
    Background* getBackgroundOnClick() const;

    bool draw();

    int getFontSize() const;
    std::string getText() const;
    Button& operator=(const Button & button);

    // From Clickable
    bool wasClicked(const Point& clickPos);

    Button();
    ~Button();
};

bool Button::draw()
{
    onDrawStart();      // This needs to be called in each object

    if(!isClicked() && m_pBackground != nullptr)
    m_pBackground->draw(m_drawPosition, m_width, m_height);

    else if(m_pBackgroundOnClick != nullptr)
    m_pBackgroundOnClick->draw(m_drawPosition, m_width, m_height);

    FontManager::Instance().renderLineOfText(font, lineLength, pos, textToRender);

    onDrawFinish();     // This needs to be called in each object
    return true;
}

Button::Button() :
    TComponent(Point(0,0)),
    m_pBackground(nullptr),
    m_pBackgroundOnClick(nullptr),
    m_text("")
{
}

Button::~Button()
{
    if(m_pBackground != nullptr)
    {
        delete m_pBackground;
        m_pBackground = nullptr;
    }
}

Button& Button::operator=(const Button & button)
{
    m_position = Point(button.getPos());
    m_pBackground = new Background()

    return *this;
}
```

Ok, I think I included all required parts of code.

Drawing content is inside `Background`'s `draw()` method.

Object called `obj` is the one passed as argument in `addObject()` method inside `GUIObject`'s constructor:

```
GUIManager::Instance().addObject(this);
```

Comment: You are getting this error while you **compile** the code???  Or when you run it?

Comment: @HansPassant When I run it.

Comment: You definitely can call a pure virtual function pretty much everywhere. Run the program in the debugger. What is the stack trace when it crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it seems like it was a very silly mistake I made. As I explained in edit I made to my question, `obj` object was the one being passed as an argument in method `addObject()` which is being called in `GUIObject`'s constructor which means that `Button`'s object itself was not yet created. Compiler didn't complain, because `GUIObject` class has declared `draw()` method, but only in runtime lack of definition for this method is found.

But anyway, thank all of you for telling me that calling pure virtual method is perfectly fine in a display list. That helped me find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility I see so far, would be if `Component` doesn't define `virtual void onDrawStart() = 0` or `virtual void onDrawFinish() = 0`. But then you should already get an error, when you instantiate `Button`.

You don't declare `m_pBackgroundOnClick` anywhere. Should it be a member of `Button`?

Answer (score -1):

> But I'd like to know, why can't I put virtual function inside Display list?

The issue has nothing to do with OpenGL display lists. Heck OpenGL display lists are compiled at runtime and don't even interact with functions on the compilation unit level.

I have the impression that you might think that a OpenGL display list will "record" ***everything*** within it. This is not the case. A OpenGL display lists records only a subset of OpenGL API calls.

---

What happens is, that `obj` is an instance of a class deriving from a base class in which `draw` has been declared as pure virtual. E.g.

```
class A {
    virtual void draw() = 0; // draw is a pure virtual function
};
```

And a derived class

```
class B : public A {
    // does not implement draw()
};
```

Now if you have in your program some pointer to A, i.e.

```
A *pA;
```

then the compiler will of course allow calls to `draw` on this pointer

```
pA->draw();
```

under the valid presumption, that pA might in fact point to a B

```
B b;

A *pA = &b;
```

But b does not implement draw, and so the call goes to nirvana.